# Does respond_to really do anything for us in testing a Model

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

When we define a model and it has some fields, sometimes in some RSpec tests I see something like this:

```
let(:network) { build(:provider_network) }

  it 'responds to provider count' do
    expect(network).to respond_to(:provider_count)
  end
```

so for example here we have had a field in the model called `provider_count` so we have created that test for it.
I wanted to see if is this really necessary and a good practice to test it? or it is just bogus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about how "useful" something is are almost always up to debate, especially in test - however, in my opinion, the test as written is so trivial as to be useless. Instead, any test that covers true functionality - as in, a test that *uses* the `provider_count` field - will also inherently test that the model responds to `provider_count`. As written, the test is sort of like `"foo".should == "foo"` What's the point?

You're essentially testing form, not function here. Unit tests should almost always test function and not form.

The only case off the top of my head where I think that this test is something other than cruft is as a prime location for documentation. For instance, if `provider_count` is a denormalized field that seems like a candidate for future removal, or is involved in a bugfix, then putting in this test as a will-break-later point for drawing future developer eyes to the test would be OK. Once their eyes are drawn, then you have documentation there that can inform them of the reason that `provider_count` cannot simply be removed or changed. It's a lightning rod for telling people the purpose for that field if you are sure that someone might be tempted to remove it.

Of course, theoretically, you would have another, more functional test somewhere else that would break if someone messed with `provider_count`, so the only value is in predicting that someone will break it and be confused as to how the other test is not passing from their change. This is so much speculation and fortune telling that I would try to avoid this impulse as an extension of YAGNI.